# Objective-C: strange behavior of Foundation collection object when using stack block under MRC

Tags: objective-c, foundation

This is my test code:

```
typedef NSObject TEST_OBJECT_TYPE;

-(void)testFunc
{
    __block TEST_OBJECT_TYPE *object = [[TEST_OBJECT_TYPE alloc] init];
    void(^block)() = ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", object.description);
    };
    NSLog(@"%@", [block class]);
    [object release];
    block();
}
```

This code is running under `Manually Reference Counting` and with `NSZombieEnabled` turned on.
The reason I turn on `NSZombie` is to make the object's memory scrambled the moment it is release.

Because the block is a stack block(the `NSLog` proved this), when the block is executed, the object is already released, so it should hit on a zombie.
This is true for my own object types and `NSObject` and `UIView`.

But when using `foundation collection objects` like `NSSet`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, this code won't hit on a zombie, it can run without any problem, why?

Comment: Typically the memory management does define, what you have to do correctly, but does not define, what happens, if you don't. There might be many reasons, one of them should be important for you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be the collection objects have internally autoreleased themselves during their initialization.

You can test this by creating your own autorelease pool and then releasing it.

```
typedef NSObject TEST_OBJECT_TYPE;

-(void)testFunc
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    __block TEST_OBJECT_TYPE *object = [[TEST_OBJECT_TYPE alloc] init];
    void(^block)() = ^{
        NSLog(@"%@", object.description);
    };
    NSLog(@"%@", [block class]);
    [object release];
    [pool release];
    block();
}
```

Comment: Testing NSSet and there is no crash.